# Quarto sub-tables over multiple pages

Tags: quarto, kable, kableextra, modelsummary

I would love to combine multiple sub-tables over two pages (i.e, either to break the table completely and have the subtable on its own page or have a "continued" for one).

This MWE demonstrates the difficulty:

```
---
format: pdf
mainfont: Times New Roman
sansfont: Times New Roman
execute: 
    echo: false
---

library(modelsummary)
library(kableExtra)
models <- list()
models[[1]] <- lm(mpg ~ hp, mtcars)
models[[2]] <- lm(mpg ~ hp + cyl + disp + qsec + wt, mtcars)

#| label: tbl-1
#| tbl-cap: "The most important table of the paper"
#| tbl-subcap: 
#|   - "My first caption"
#|   - "Second caption"
#|   - "Third caption as well"
#| layout: [[100], [-10], [33.3], [-10], [33.3], [-10], [33.3]]

datasummary_skim(mtcars) |> kable_styling()
datasummary_correlation(mtcars)
modelsummary(models) |> kable_styling(latex_options=c("repeat_header"))
```

Any ideas?